# Solution for "Number.toFixed() digits argument must be between 0 and 100" problem in InputNumber Ant.Design

Tags: javascript, antd

When you use InputNumber of Ant.Design and user provides an input like:

```
.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

you get the component crashed with error:

```
index.js:42 RangeError: toFixed() digits argument must be between 0 and 100
    at Number.toFixed (<anonymous>)
```

What can be done to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is cased by the code in InputNumber.toPrecisionAsStep (InputNumber.js:625):

```
var precision = Math.abs(this.getMaxPrecision(num));

if (!isNaN(precision)) {
   return Number(num).toFixed(precision); // <<= HERE
}
```

So by setting `precision` value explicitly you can solve the problem.

```
<InputNumber min={ 1 } max={ 100 } precision={ 1 } />
```

Alternatively, you restrict the input for only integers:

```
function toInteger( val ) {
  const int = parseInt( val, 10 );
  return isNaN( int ) ? 0 : int;
}
```

within the component:

```
 <InputNumber formatter={ toInteger } />
```